# Regex replace word while preserving spaces/punctuation

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to go through a document and change all instances of a name using regular expressions in Java. My code looks something like this:

```
Pattern replaceWordPattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)" + replaceWord + "^|\\W");
```

followed by:

```
String line = matcher.replaceAll("Alice");
```

The problem is that this does not preserve the spaces or punctuation or other non-word characters that followed. If I had "Jack jumped" it becomes "Alicejumped". Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\W` consumes the space after the replaceWord. Replace `^|\\W` with word boundary `\\b` which does not consume symbols. Consider doing same for the first delimiter group, as I suspect you do not want to consume anything there too.

```
Pattern replaceWordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + replaceWord + "\\b");
```

If semantic of word boundaries is not suitable for you, consider using [lookahead and lookbehind constructs](http://fiddle.re/c33ea6) which do not consume input too.

Answer (score -3):

You're missing brackets on the second non-whitespace character expression:

```
Pattern replaceWordPattern = Pattern.compile("[^|\\s]" + replaceWord + "[^|\\W]");
```

Comment: Your regular expression syntax is incorrect, it should be `( ... )` not a character class. Also this will not match what the OP is after.